# Boundary condition for $\Box\vec{E}(t,\vec{x})=0$ that preserves scale-invariance

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, scale-invariance

In short, this is a question about the symmetry of a differential equation preserved by its boundary condition.

In free space, the vector wave equation satisfied by the electric and the magnetic field is of the form $$\Box\vec{F}(t,\vec{x})=0$$ where $\Box$ is the D'Alembertian operator and ${\vec F}$ is either the electric field ${\vec E}$ or the magnetic field ${\vec B}$.

This equation is scale-invariant (See Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_invariance#Classical_electromagnetism)).  This leads us to draw the conclusion that if $\vec{F}(t,{\vec x})$ is a solution, $\vec{F}(\alpha t,\alpha{\vec x})$ is also a solution where $\alpha$ is a dimensionless real number. This suggests that if there is a plane-wave solution with frequency $\omega$ and wavenumber $k$, there is also a solution with frequency $\alpha\omega$ and wavenumber $\alpha k$. See an excellent answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/258298/164488).

However, I have two doubts.

1. But for the scale-invariance of the wave equation to survive in its solutions, I think the boundary conditions must also be scale-invariant. I am not totally sure which boundary condition, in vacuum proper, will be scale-invariant and also lead to nonzero field solutions.

   I think, specific type of initial condition for the fields specified at $t=0$ and boundary condition specified at $|\vec x|\to\infty$ might have a chance to preserve scale-invariance of the differential equation because $0\times\alpha=0$ and $\infty\times\alpha\to\infty$. I am not sure. If $${\vec F}(0,\vec x)=\vec{u}(\vec x),~~{\vec F}(t,|\vec x|\to\infty)=\vec v(t),...{\rm etc}$$ what kind of choice will preserve scale-invariance?
2. There is a second issue that I want to understand. Once adequate BCs are specified, and the problem becomes well-posed, we will have a unique solution. But doesn't that mean if the solution is a plane-wave one, there is only one possible $k$ and $\omega$. Please address this one, too.

If someone could explain this, I will very much appreciate it.